# CruiseControl .Net problems after server is restarted

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I've got a problem with CruiseControl .Net (version 1.4.3.4023) in that when the server is restarted, a random selection of projects are 'broken' even though the codebase has not changed.

As the servers in our place are restarted every Sunday evening, my job Monday morning is to run through CCTray, starting each project in turn, so that our output display monitor shows a green (fixed) status.

I can replicate the problem, simply by stop/starting the CruiseControl service, as this does exactly the same thing.  Again, a random selection of projects appear as failed.

Any suggestions as to how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, have you checked the CCNet logfile?  That will most likely have your solution.

My guess is that your SCC server may have been inaccessible for a period of time for some reason (scheduled reboots/etc?) and CCNET has "given up" on reaching it for a handful of projects.  We had the same problem, and I believe that it went away when we upgraded to CCNET 1.5.

Comment: We're using Subversion, and the SVN server and repository are on the same machine as CruiseControl is... 

But then why would this still happen if in the middle of the day I were to stop/start the CruiseControl process? SVN is still running...  hmmm.

Comment: That is strange.  The log really should tell the tale.  Check your ccnet log and edit your post with the build failures/errors that you see.  My guess is that you'll see something happening around the time you restart.  Maybe some bad configuration or something is causing some evil to happen.

Comment: I'll have to wait for a quiet gap in the day and repro the error to get the logs, as the guys are using it at present and the rolling logs have rolled off.